# Proper way to create ssl socket

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, https

I am trying to create a simple secure ssl web server, but I do not know if the server is working properly.  It makes the connection just fine, but I want to know if I am accidentally sending plain-text. Also, am I making any mistakes that would cause it to be insecure?

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import BaseHTTPServer
import ssl

class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = 'test.html'
        return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

Handler = MyRequestHandler
server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), Handler)
server.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(server.socket, certfile='server.pem', server_side=True)
server.serve_forever()
```

This is not for anything of vital security, it is just for learning about the protocol.